# Adding comments in a properties file line by line

Tags: java, properties

This is something which I want to do in properties file

```
#Comments about key Value pair 1
Key_1=value_1


#Comments about key Value pair 2
Key_2=value_2

#Comments about key Value pair 3
Key_3=value_3
```

Right now what I am able to do with my file is

```
#OMG, It works!
#Mon Oct 14 01:22:10 IST 2013
Key_1=Value_1
Key_2=Value_2
```

Is there any way of doing such a thing

Comment: Is it not working, can you elaborate?

Comment: yes, that's working fine functionality wise, but for the sake of formatting I wanted to keep it that way only.
I SO'd and found out that I cannot add multiline comments, But I have no idea what are multiline comments.
So I thought that this might be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/index.html) to write and read Properties files, specifically the [setComment()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfigurationLayout.html#setComment%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) function in a [PropertiesConfigurationLayout](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/PropertiesConfigurationLayout.html) which allows you to specify a comment for each property.

Note that above links refer to Commons Configuration v1.x, while v2.0 has been released in the meantime, which has different package names.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do what you want using the standard [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

You can, of course, do this by writing the file out yourself. The main thing that you need to be careful of is embedded newlines, and embedded `=` and `:` in your keys. However, if you really want to be able to store individual comments about each pair, then you probably want a class that maps from `<key>⇒<value,comment>`, and then use that map to generate your properties file.

Answer (score 0):

I think basically you want the property with a comment with description. If that is the case

```
Properties props=new Properties();
props.add("key","value");
FileOutputStream output=new FileOutputStream("props.dat",true); //so that it won't create a new file since it is 'true')
 props.store(output,"Sample properties");
```