# Comments are getting deleted after updating .properties file

Tags: java, file

I have a .properties file which have number of comments in it, when I try to update the content of the file other than the comments, even though my comments are disappearing, how to retain my comments?

Here is the config.properties file:

```
#name of user
name=user1
#id of user
id=id1
```

and the code to update the properties file, I used

```
public class SetLog {
    public static void setPath()
    {
        File file = new File("./config.properties");
           Properties prop = new Properties();
           FileInputStream objInput = null;
           try {
            objInput = new FileInputStream(file);
            prop.load(objInput);
            objInput.close();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./config.properties");
//update the content
               prop.setProperty("name", "user2");
              prop.store(out, null);
               out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}              
    }

}
```

After I run the above code, properties file content changed to:

```
name=user2
id=id1
```

But I want in this format:

```
 #name of user
 name=user2
 #id of user
 id=id1
```

How to retain my comments, please help!

Comment: Maybe the XML format? storeToXML and loadFromXML? That would facilitate using Unicode in the form of UTF-8 too.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in a similar question: [Adding comments in a Property File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349585/adding-comments-in-a-properties-file-line-by-line). Basically it boils down to using the Apache Commons extension to read and write Property Files.

Comment: If it was answered already, then it is better to flag this question as a duplicate.

Comment: I've flagged it as such, Tom

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the characters in the file and ignore those lines beginning with # .

See this [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/53734-java-code-to-modify-properties-file-and-preserve-comments/)

Comment: I think the OP desires to _maintain_ comments. Which are not kept in Properties and hence disappear on storing a Properties.

Comment: yes, once the comments are read, they can be written back to the file when the file is being updated with new properties. In fact, even better,  comments can be updated with newer comment history and\or date time stamp.

Comment: @E2241, I kind of need the solution of the problem mentioned in the link you provided, but I am not able to understand the code, can't we achieve it in a simple way where we can keep our comments as it is while updating the key values?

Comment: I am afraid there is no other built in class for Properties at least of which I am aware. You will have to read the lines from the file  beginning with # and then write them back for the comments.